# PHPExcel write html file into existing xlsx file

Tags: excel-2007, phpexcel

I have a template file that I fill using PHPExcel. But I have terms and conditions that are saved in database with html tags and inline css. Now these terms and conditions are subject to change so I cant put it into template. So only solution is t take it from database and put it inside created template but I have no clue how to open xlsx file and insert .html file inside it perhaps as second sheet.

This is my current code:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

And of course there is lot of code that specifically deal with writing data to excel file but that is working perfectly.

Could someone please explain how could I go about doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply insert an HTML file inside an xlsx file

The latest develop branch of PHPExcel does include an HTML to Rich Text wizard that will take a block of HTML markup and convert it to a Rich Text object that can then be stored in a cell, and `/Examples/42richText.php` demonstrates how it can be used. At present, this only covers basic markup tags (`<br />`, `<font>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<ins>`, `<del>`, etc) and doesn't handle inline style in any way. However, it might provide the basis for what you want with some additional work.

Comment: hope they find a way about it, it was really big help when it comes to complicated excel layout.